# Problems using fplot and function handle in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to plot values from 0 to 7 in x axis, so I though I have to use fplot and I was reading that I have to use handle functions. I tried to follow the samples on internet, but I can not plot the points. The main code is the next:

```
 Y=[-1;
     1;
     1]
 X=[3 0.2 1;
    1 0.3 1;
    4 0.5 1]
 num= length(Y)
 eta= 0.01
 for i = 1 : num 
    if ~isequal(sign(W.* X(i,:)),Y(i).*ones(1,3))
        W = W .+ eta .*(X(i,:) .* Y(i));
        [line] = @(x) line_percep(W,X,i); 
    end
  end
    fplot(line, [0 7]);
```

And I included an auxiliary function:

```
function [line] = line_percep(vW,vX,vi)
  a=(-vW(1)/vW(3));
  b=(-vW(2)/vW(3));
  line=vX(vi,1)*a + vX(vi,2)*b;
end
```

Now I have plot the graph, but without any line. I guess is a problem in the calculation. Thank you "Benoit_11" for your help.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as to what kind of error you get, but try running your code in a script (i.e. not from the Command Window) using `hold all` (or `hold on`) to plot multiple lines and `numel(W)` as the loop counter (`num` in your code is not defined...you probably forgot to write it) and that should work.

Anyhow let's say you save a script containing this code:

```
clc
clear

X=[3 0.2 1;
1 0.3 1;
4 0.5 1];
W=[.3, .8, .2];

hold all
for i = 1 : numel(W)    
   fh = @(x) fun(W,X,i)
   fplot(fh, [0 7]);
end
```

And then your function `fun` is saved as well, then running the script produces the following graph:

[image]

Comment: I got an error on the Octave Editor when I run the program. That is the next:
error: 'wk_W' undefined near line 2 column 6
error: called from:
error:   C:\Plotting.m at line 2, column 4

Should I include the function in another file or should I leave at the beginning of the source code? It didn't recognize the variable despite the variable is in the arguments.

Comment: You should create a separate file for your function `fun`.

Comment: So did you try it? I'm curious :)

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried in different ways, but I haven't gotten. I put apart the function in another file to calculate the line and in the main function I call it. However, I have had troubles here: line(i) = @(x) line_percep(W,X,i); The name of the function is line_percep and carry out a sum of the arguments. After this is going to pass through a for loop to add points to the line. At the end the main program plot the result.

Comment: I divided into the function in one file called line_percep.m with the next content:
function line = line_percep(vW,vX,vi)
  a=-vW(1)/vW(3);
  b=-vW(2)/vW(3);
  line=vX(vi,1)*a + vX(vi,2)*b;
end
And the main function:
Y=[-1;
-1;
-1]
X=[3 0.2 1;
1 0.3 1;
2 0.7 1]
W=[.3, .8, -2.2];
num= length(Y)
eta= 0.01
line= 0*ones(num,1)
for i = 1 : num %cycle goes through every row
    if ~isequal(sign(W.* X(i,:)),Y(i).*ones(1,3)) 
      W = W .+ eta .*(X(i,:) .* Y(i));   
      line(i) = @(x) line_percep(W,X,i);      
     end      
end
fplot(line, [0 7]);

Thank your for your help.

Comment: This is hard to read; please add this code to your question and format it so its easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: `<p>`The next is the main function or procedure:`</p>`
`<pre><code>`Y=[-1;
        1;
        1]
    X=[3 0.2 1;
       1 0.3 1;
       4 0.5 1]
    num= length(Y)
    eta= 0.01
    for i = 1 : num 
        if ~isequal(sign(W.* X(i,:)),Y(i).*ones(1,3))
            W = W .+ eta .*(X(i,:) .* Y(i));
            [line] = @(x) line_percep(W,X,i); 
        end
    end
    fplot(line, [0 7]);
`</code></pre>`

Comment: I am sorry, I continue looking around how to do format in comments on Stackoverflow. The format is not available for comments, so it's different.

Comment: No problem. Instead of adding the code in the comments, try to edit your question. It's going to be easy to format then. Thanks!

Comment: What is `W` at the beginning of the script?

Comment: Possible initial Weights that are modified based on X and Y. X matrix includes X,Y points and the last column on X is dummy (always 1). The Y values are binary (yes or not).

Comment: At the end the line is created by w3x2+w2x1+w1=0
Or
x2=-w2/w3*x1-w1/w3